# Cuál es comando de borrar la caché de preview para SwiftUI?

Tags: xcode

No hay manera de que cargue el preview en Xcode, he recurrido a `DevCleaner`y ese caso no ha funcionado la mágia.

Alguna otra manera de como eliminar el preview de xcode de forma manual?

Answer (score 0):

### Pasos a seguir en Xcode y terminal

1.- Con Xcode abierto: "Clean build folder"

2.- Borrar el derived data: puedes encontrar el folder dentro de Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Derived Data

3.- Cerrar Xcode

4.- Ejecutar en Terminal:
`xcrun simctl --set previews delete all`

5.- Reabrir Xcode y dejar que se genere todo antes de hacer build